# Run shell script with su errors

Tags: bash

I have a script that is run by root and looks like this

```
curl -O some stuff
mv it to user guest directory
su - guest -c sh /home/guest/script.sh
```

Everything works fine until the last `su` command. It gives me the error

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
```

How can I make the user `guest` execute the `script.sh` using `su`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [man su](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html):

> SYNOPSIS 
>         
>
>     su [options] [-] [user [argument...]]

You changed the order of the parameters.
Try this way:

```
su -c "/path/to/sh /home/guest/script.sh" - guest
```

Note the quotes `"` before the start and after the end of the command. Moreover, I suggest you to use absolute path also for `sh`.